# Removing certain separators from csv file with pandas or csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-manipulation

I've got multiple csv files, which I received in the following line format:

-8,000E-04,2,8E+1,

The first and the third comma are meant to be  decimal separators, the second comma is a column delimiter and I think the last one is supposed to indicate a new line. So the csv should only consist of two columns and I have to prepare the data in order to plot it. Therefore I need to specify the two columns as x and y to plot the data.I tried removing or replacing the separators in every line but by doing that I'm  no longer able to specify the two columns. Is there a way to remove certain separators from every line of the csv?

Comment: You said that you replaced the separators. Did you mean replacing the decimal delimiters with "." or replacing the column seperators with something like ";"? The first one should work out of the box if you didn't miss anything. The second one needs the `sep=';'` keyword argument in the `read_csv` call.

Comment: How can I write a code which can differentiate between a decimal delimiter and a column separator to replace them individually without replacing every comma by a dot or semicolon ?

Comment: Have a look at the solution from Péter Leéh. He is using a regular expression to do it. This should work if all of your numbers follow the pattern you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace the second comma using regex. Well, I'm definitely not an expert at it, but I've managed to come up with this:

```py
import re

s = "-8,000E-04,2,8E+1,"
pattern = "^([^,]*,[^,]*),(.*),$"

grps = re.search(pattern, s).groups()

res = [float(s.replace(",", ".")) for s in grps]
print(res)
# [-0.0008, 28.0]
```

Sample csv file:

```
-8,000E-04,2,8E+1,
6,0E-6,-45E+2,
-5,550E-6,-6,2E+1,
```

And you can do something like this:

```py
x = []
y = []

regex = re.compile("^([^,]*,[^,]*),(.*),$")

with open("a.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        result = regex.search(line).groups()
        x.append(float(result[0].replace(",", ".")))
        y.append(float(result[1].replace(",", ".")))
```

The result is:

```
print(x, y)
# [-0.0008, 6e-06, -5.55e-06] [28.0, -4500.0, -62.0]
```

I'm not sure this is the most efficient way, but it works.

Comment: hey, thanks for your suggestion ! I tried  running this code with your sample csv file but I get the following error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups' Is there a way to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string returned by reading line as follow

```
line="-8,000E-04,2,8E+1,"
list_string = line.split(',')
x= float(list_string[0]+"."+list_string[1])
y= float(list_string[2]+"."+list_string[3])

print(x,y)
```

Result is

```
-0.0008 28.0
```

you can arrange `x` and `y` in columns also or whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

Here a short program in python to convert your csv-files

```
import csv

f1 = "in_test.csv"
f2 = "out_test.csv"
with open(f1, newline='') as csv_reader:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_reader, delimiter=',')
    with open(f2, mode='w', newline='') as csv_writer:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_writer, delimiter=";")
        for row in reader:
            out_row = [row[0] + '.' + row[1], row[2] + '.' + row[3]]
            writer.writerow(out_row)
```

Sample input:

```
-8,000E-04,2,8E+1,
-2,000E-03,2,7E+2,
```

Sample output:

```
-8.000E-04;2.8E+1
-2.000E-03;2.7E+2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! If I run this code I get an IndexError: list index out of range. I think its because I tried to use it on a file in which the first numbers (-8.000E-04, -2.000E-03, etc.) consist of more digits (-7.000000E-04). Is there a way to fix this error?

Comment: I think its not the digits as the code is not sensitive for that as it uses strings. But you show a number which has a ‘.’ As separator In -7.000000E-04 that means if that is in the input file there aren’t 4 members for row! So you get an index error. The code presumes all you numbers have ‘,’ separators.